# Ten sons of Haman and the Ten Plagues

Tags: purim, egypt, plagues-makkos, haman, pharaoh

Are there any connections made between the ten sons of Haman being killed, and the ten plagues that afflicted the Egyptians?

(Also accepting peoples own chidushim on this topic. Please specify if the answer is your own pirush.  If it is sourced from elsewhere please CITE THE SOURCE as accurately as possible)

Comment: The Zohar (II, 243a) explains there are 10 sefirot of the sitra achra that parallel (lhavdil) the 10 sefirot of kedusha. Haman's sons represent the former, whereas the plagues are knegged the former in that each is a revelation that Hashem controls the whole universe, including all of its sefirot. This is how the two are related. One possible vort (mine) might be that in Pesach, Hashem showed how He controls the 10 sefirot of kedusha, and in Purim He completed His picture of His power by showing that He also can smash the 10 "evil" sefirot whenever He wants.

Comment: Im having difficulty locating that, can you please add a link to Sefaria zohar or possibly be more specific on the wording of the Zohar.

Comment: See https://www.sefaria.org/Zohar%2C_Pekudei.44.435

Comment: Im sorry, but i don't see any mention or reference to the ten plagues or the ten sons at the location that you cited.

Comment: It just discusses the sefirot of the sitra achra there. I don't remember where I saw the connection between them and the 10 sons

Comment: Ah okay, thanks for the info! I don't think this specific Zohar is relevant to the subject of this question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145816/discussion-between-targum-and-rabbi-kaii).